# Visual c# VSTO Excel Renaming the worksheet codename property

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, worksheet

Need to add a new worksheet to a workbook via an excel add-in (C# VSTO). The sheets itself will contain a warning message stating something like: `If you can see this sheet you don't have the add-in installed.`

The sheet will be hidden automatically if the add-in is installed, Trouble is there are 1k+ workbooks in SharePoint - hence my approach of adding and hiding worksheets as the workbooks are opened by users.

I am trying to add a worksheet but then change the `CodeName`.

This is possible in VBA with the code:

`ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Wks.CodeName).Name = strSheetName`

Visual C# goes some way towards hinting this might be allowed with the `using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;` and the undocumented `_CodeName` (Reserved for internal use.)

Here is what I have tried:

```
Excel.Worksheet Wks = Wkb.Sheets["CRM365"];

string strSheetName = "WksWarnings"

Wkb.VBProject.VBComponents(Wks._CodeName).Name = strSheetName;
```

Of course, it doesn't work. Mainly because VBComponents is a non-invocable member.
All the documentation I have found so far states that `CodeName` property is read-only - which isn’t always true, see VBA example above.

Before I get the replies "why bother, etc.." I'm of the school of thought that computers don't tell us what to do - we tell them. (Until they rise up and become our overlords), also all the other sheets have the code names defined.

Is this one case where Visual Basic outshines Visual C#?

Comment: You could setup a page in the `backstage` area of the ribbon xml.  Here's an example https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help/blob/master/CS/Ribbon.xml#L596-L664

Comment: Is this a VSTO application-level add-in, or a VSTO document-level customization? If the latter, it definitely won't work as VSTO leverages this as part of the customization. Then there's also the question whether the machine this is running on allows access to the VB project - by installation default this is *not* allowed, so anything the VBE namespace will be blocked by the Office application. allowing access to the VBE is a security risk.

Comment: Hi, thank for the input - its the forma (VSTO application-level add-in), I usual do most programming in VBA, (but decided to get with the future). So I have the "Trust access to the VBA project model object", checked, and various network locations added in the trust center..